# YouTube API, how to post to different channels after approval with Python

Tags: python, youtube-api, google-developers-console

I was using this program here to post in YouTube: https://github.com/EnriqueStrange/AutomatedYoutube

I have an account with 4 YouTube Channels and I want to be able to automatically post on the different channels. I created 4 different OAuth 2.0 Client IDs, and when running the first the browser opens, I give permission to use the code on one channel and it uploads video fine. But when using the other ID's it just posts in the same channel I originally gave approval instead of asking me permission with the different OAuth ID.

Any idea on how to specify a key for a specific channel?

[image]

Created 4 different json files with the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and expected it would ask permission everytime I ran a new key and link it with a different channel.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one client id. You can authorize the application four times once for each channel. Just store the refresh token. There is no need for a different client.

In the example below you would have a separate 'token.json' for each channel.

```
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
```

you only need a single 'credentials.json'

Comment: Oh, the github code does have a github folder with a second json with "access_token" key. I'm still a little confused on how to implement it and didn't understand the code you posted, but I'll look up some tutorials and see if I can figure it out now that I know that's the problem! Thanks, I tried to one up your comment but site won't let me.

Comment: I will try to find some time tomorrow to make a full tutorial,  but I'm a little pressed for time

Comment: Cool, I think I might have solved it by using one credentials json like you said, but deleted the content on the token json and made 4 files. I created 4 unique tokens, but I don't know for sure cause I exceeded my upload quota which seems to be less than ten uploads.

Comment: sounds about right YouTube API is cost based costs around 1600 quote points for an upload default quote limit is 10k.